# How to Apply polyfill in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polyfills

Hi i have built an app using Javascript ES6 it work well on some devices but some older devices show errors, i think it is because they do not support ES6.

below is the error from console. Note: this error only come in some devices

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

and here is line of code that show error

```
for (const [rowName, value] of Object.entries(allRows))
```

So kindly help me with this how i can do something to make it work on all devices.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polyfill provides an implementation of a **function** which has a native implementation in sufficiently modern environments. You can't polyfill **syntax**.

If you want to support JS runtimes which don't support syntax then you need to provide them with code that they do support.

You can either:

- Write code that way in the first place
- Transpile it using a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: so is this error is because of js version or what?
because it is working on most of the devices.

Comment: Yes. The JS runtime on the device doesn't support destructuring syntax.

Comment: i used webpack now to overcome this issue. can you kindly up vote my question